# How to edit from the datagridview and save new changes

Tags: c#, datagridview, edit, savechanges

I have a resource file which i read the data and load it to the grid-view. now i want the user to be able to edit from the grid and click save button which will save it as a new file of resx? how do i do that? this is the code for reading the file.

```
oDataSet = new DataSet();
//now am reading the files from the path that is selected
XmlReadMode omode = oDataSet.ReadXml(PathSelection);

for (int i = 0; i < oDataSet.Tables[2].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string comment = oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][2].ToString();
    string font = Between(comment, "[Font]","[/Font]");
    string datestamp = Between(comment, "[DateStamp]", "[/DateStamp]");
    string commentVal = Between(comment, "[Comment]", "[/Comment]");

    string[] row = new string[] 
    { 
        oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][0].ToString(),
        oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][1].ToString(), 
        font, 
        datestamp, 
        commentVal
    };

    Gridview_Input.Rows.Add(row);

    cboLanguage.Enabled = true;
    btnNewfile.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try refresh your dataGridView each button click.

```
datagridviewName.update();
datagridviewName.refresh();
```

Comment: I edited and try to save, no changes occurred on my resx file.